# How to install mcrypt extension in xampp

Tags: php, xampp, mcrypt

how to install mcrypt in xampp on windows?

My PHP Version 7.0.5 and xampp pack have not **mcrypt** **extension** so how can i install mcrypt on xampp ?

Comment: Did you try : http://www.myoddweb.com/2010/11/18/install-mcrypt-for-php-on-windows/

Comment: @Rishi i had exactly the same post in my Copy'N' Paste :)

Comment: 90% we found the same solution, Only if we want to search. I think Dhaval not tried this.

Comment: i tried every solution. @Rishi yes is seen this link. do you found “php_mcrypt.dll” file in php7 package ?

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. The mcrypt-extension is deprecated will be removed in PHP 7.2. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: Tried the same link for 7.0.3,7.2 but it did not worked out. How to replace mcrypt for ongoing project

Answer (score 42):

First, you should download the suitable version for your system from here: https://pecl.php.net/package/mcrypt/1.0.3/windows

Then, you should copy `php_mcrypt.dll` to `../xampp/php/ext/` and enable the extension by adding `extension=mcrypt` to your `xampp/php/php.ini` file.

Comment: This worked for me with Magento 1.9.2.1 installation with PHP 7.3 on xampp

Comment: Make sure you **restart** XAMPP.  Worked for me for PHP 7.4 on XAMPP.

Answer (score 6):

The recent versions of XAMPP for Windows runs PHP 7.x which are NOT compatible with mbcrypt.
If you have a package like Laravel that requires mbcrypt, you will need to install an older version of XAMPP. OR, you can run XAMPP with multiple versions of PHP by downloading a PHP package from Windows.PHP.net, installing it in your XAMPP folder, and configuring php.ini and httpd.conf to use the correct version of PHP for your site.

Answer (score 2):

you should install mcrypt with pecl on your xampp server:

```
./bin/pecl install mcrypt
```

then add to php.ini this code (extension block):

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

Comment: thank you! Most answers were telling me to use `apt`, but that would install the mcrypt along with php 8.x which I didn't want. This did the trick perfectly. I also had to `apt install libmcrypt-dev` for pecl to compile this btw.

Answer (score 0):

Do not provide a version number when you run the command:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name 4.2.*
```

Use this instead:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app
```

Answer (score -3):

Right from the PHP Docs:
PHP 5.3 Windows binaries uses the static version of the MCrypt library, no DLL are needed.

http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.requirements.php

But if you really want to download it, just go to the mcrypt sourceforge page

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcrypt/files/?source=navbar

Comment: This standard answer that seems to show up everywhere is not valid here, since the asker made it clear he is using PHP 7.0.5.