# XAMPP 7.2.5 , mcrypt not loaded , required for opencart 2.3

Tags: php, xampp, opencart, mcrypt

I'm trying to install Opencart 2.3.0.2 on my local machine (mac osx). Downloaded XAMPP 7.2.5 , but can't install opencart because it needs `mcrypt`.

When I run `phpinfo()` I do see

```
'--with-mcrypt=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles'
```

but no other mentions of mcrypt. So I guess it's not loading?

How can I activate mcrypt? PHP version is 7.2.5

Comment: Is there a header named mcrypt in the phpinfo output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install mcrypt extension in xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522384/how-to-install-mcrypt-extension-in-xampp)

Comment: In the manual it says: This feature was DEPRECATED in PHP 7.1.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.2.0.

Alternatives to this feature include:

Sodium (available as of PHP 7.2.0)
OpenSSL
http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mcrypt.php

Comment: @Jonathan no :(

Comment: @Stony thnx .. I will check it out

Comment: @Arno hmm .. ok .. so OpenCart needs to update that .. Or downgrade my php

Comment: Yeah .. I downgraded to PHP 5.6 :) thnx all

Comment: You could downgrade to 7.0 or 7.1. Both versions are a lot faster than 5.6 :)

Comment: @Arno hehe .. yeah .. In the end I did that :) I went for 7.1 .. Now Opencart,XAMPP and Laravel works

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an old laravel project, I found the easier way to solve it

- download an older version of xampp call it xampp2
- go to change the path to xampp2/php in environment variables