# Unable to load php_mcrypt.dll while installing composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php, mcrypt

While installing the composer im getting the following error... Anyone can help me to fix it.

The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe
```

The **php.ini** used by your command-line PHP is: `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`

A setting in your **php.ini** could be causing the problem:

```
Either the 'extension_dir' value is incorrect or the dll does not exist.
```

**Program Output:**

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mcrypt.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mcrypt.dll (The specified module could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_mcrypt.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Please report us the php version.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522384/how-to-install-mcrypt-extension-in-xampp

Comment: PHP 7.2.6 version

Comment: Error says `C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_mcrypt.dll.dll` is missing. I think it should be `C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_mcrypt.dll`. So please check in you php.ini there is a spell mistake.

Answer (score 1):

php_mcrypt.so.dll extension is deprecated in higher versions of PHP interpreter.
The extension may not be installed on your PHP interpreter, but the line activating the extension may exist in your php.ini setting file.
Go to the directory that you have installed PHP interpreter (which usually is C:\PHP). Find the 'C:\PHP\php.ini' file and open it in a text editor.

if the line containing the phrase extension=mcrypt.so is not commented out, put a semicolon at the beginning of the line.

```
;extension=mcrypt.so
```

Comment: In my case it was necessary to comment the loading of `php_mcrypt.dll` in php.ini, but indeed it's the same kind of solution.